# Do modern day desktop CPU's (such as the Skylake) still have a Northbridge Southbridge IC on die?

Tags: integrated-circuit, cpu

Would it be integrated into the "Memory & I/O Interface section of the die or has it been phased out and all functionality is now part of this IC? I've included a die photo of the Intel "Skylake" die layout here.

[image]

Comment: Please define what you mean by "embedded" vs "integrated" vs "part of this IC". Because to me these all mean the same thing. The three options I know of are: external, different die but same package, and same die. If it's on the same die, it's on the same die. I don't see any distinction past that point. The three terms you have used all mean the last option to me. (Not that I know the answer to your question but it lacks a bit of clarity and knowing that might answer your own question).

Comment: When was the north or south (long gone, now, I believe) bridge ever on the CPU die??? Never in my experience. (I worked at Intel on the BX chipset, which at the time did include a South Bridge IC -- the source of about 50% of the chipset bugs at the time.) Where did you get the idea? The CPUs I worked with sported a backside bus for access to L2 cache and a frontside bus for access to other CPU ICs, the memory chipset, and the TPA (third party adapter.) There was a maximum of 6 bus loads for the frontside bus. L2 was a separate die wirebonded to the CPU, then.

Comment: @jonk If Wiki is to be believed https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_(computing), 10 years

Comment: @DKNguyen South bridge was retired, so far as I'm aware, as the legacy bus (ISA) was much of its reason and much of the source of chipset bugs. I suppose they may have just retired the legacy support and still retained the name. In that case, it dates after my time at Intel. So I may be mistaken on the naming. But I still have never heard that it was included on-die with the CPU core die.

Comment: @jonk That Wiki is Southbridge but in it talks about Nortbridge. Or it's a typo, who knows?

Comment: @DKNguyen The on-die graphics section is new to me, as shown in OP's picture. We had a special AGP graphics interface with relaxed memory ordering (graphics doesn't really care whether pixel A or pixel B get there first.) That seems like a terrible waste of good die space to me. However, it wouldn't be a waste if that is actually the graphics CPU, I guess. So that must be what it is. It makes me wonder about compilers that may use both the available CPUs and also the GPU for code. I pity the compiler-writers, if so.

Comment: @jonk That part is the graphics card now

Comment: @DKNguyen The GPU was on the graphics card in my day, too. The AGP (which today I wonder if it even exists) was just a BIU on the memory controller IC with relaxed ordering. It otherwise looked like PCI, transaction-wise. Just the FIFOs operated differently. I never saw the GPU on the same die as the CPUs. Didn't know it was *ever* done. So that leaves me curious about the picture.

Comment: In recent years (10 years?) it's on the die for basic stuff driven by AMD. For games you still need a dedicated card.

Answer (score 1):

Intel retired the North/South bridge chipset configuration in the late 2000s (and AMD years before), so neither exists in a modern computer.

Some things that were within the north or south  bridge still exist. The memory controller for example is now on the CPU die (except for some AMD systems were it's on a second chip). The PCIe controllers have been split between the CPU and an external chip (intel PCH). Graphics, if integrated, are nearly always on the CPU so that they can be close to the memory controller. Usually when sources say that the NB is on the CPU what they really mean is that the memory controller is on die.

Intel and AMD also make some SoC optimized CPU dies that bring more components onto the CPU for use in mobile or small form factor devices. These include things like USB, thunderbolt or networking.